# How i can get the array ID from a page to another redirect page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, redirect

This is my first post. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find what I was looking for. So I have this file that break the content of the post and has a read more:

```
<?php

include('../root/admin/includes/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "\n";
    echo truncate($row['Content'], "article.php", "article_id", $row['ID']);
}

//function to truncate text and show read more link  
function truncate($mytext, $link, $var, $id) {
    //Number of characters to show  
    $chars = 25;
    $mytext = substr($mytext, 0, $chars);
    $mytext = substr($mytext, 0, strrpos($mytext, ' '));
    $mytext = $mytext . " <a href='$link?$var=$id'>read more...</a>";
    return $mytext;
}

?>
```

Now I have and this file

```
<?php

include('includes/connect.php');
$id = isset($_GET['ID']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">No Posts Were Found</td></tr>";
} else {
    while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<div class='perigrama'><div class='titlos'><h2><a href='#'>" . $post['Title'] . "</a></h2></div><div class='infos'><p>Posted by <a href='#'>" . $post['Author'] . "</a> on March 10, 2011 | <a href='#'>Full article</a></p></div><div class='image'><img src='#' width='540' height='300'></div><div class='content'><p>" . $post['Content'] . "</p></div><div class='more'><p><a href='#'>Full details</a></p></div></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

And this file that I want to output the post from the database based on ID here, when I click read more:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../test/testdivformascss.css">
    <body>
        <?php
        include('functions1.php');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output that I have like this when I hit read more it redirect me to the right page id but says me that No posts where found.

If you could tell me a way on how to do this I will be glad to see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you hear of SQL injection? Read about it.

Comment: you should use the mysqli_ functions or PDO instead of using mysql_ functions. Aside from that, what's the content of the `$link` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$id=isset($_GET['ID']);
```

to

```
$id=isset($_GET['article_id']) ? (int)$_GET['article_id'] : 0;
```

`$id = isset($_GET['ID']);` - this returns bool and moreover it will be always false because there is no ID in `$_GET`

Your link looks like `$mytext = $mytext . " <a href='$link?$var=$id'>read more...</a>";`

it is parsed by truncate function which outputs

`<a href='article.php?article_id=SOME_ID'>read more...</a>`

so you should use on `$_GET['article_id']` to get this id and you should cast it to int by (int) or `intval()`

Two more things.

1. Your code is very dangerous you should really read and google some topics that covers **SQL_INJECTION**
2. **Mysql_* functions are depracated** and will be removed in future. Use **PDO** or **Mysqli** instead. These engines have something called prepared statements and with param binding you will not have to take care of proper escaping.

Comment: Thank you my friend it worked... i know that has a lot of problems and is dangerous...i do that only for testing. I have only 2 months that i study php and mysql and for that reason is so dangerous :P i surely must try mysqli or PDO ...only read mysql just for basic things and understanding. Thanks for the tips :)